# How to update and return all array elements which matches a condition?

Tags: mongodb

I tried the below and understood `$` returns first matching element.

```
vardate=newDate();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-30);

db.getCollection('status').find({
  'data.end_ts': {
    '$lte': date
  },
  $or: [
    {
      "data.risk_status": 'inactive'
    },
    {
      "data.risk_status": 'expired'
    }
  ]
},
{
  "data.$": 1
})
```

Then I planned to remove `projection` and do the removal job at java.

Here, the problem is that I need to remove and insert into another collection. Hence, I can't just use delete.

I came up with another way so that I can avoid conditions at java.

```
db.getCollection('status').aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
          $or: [
            {
              "data.risk_status": 'inactive'
            },
            {
              "data.risk_status": 'expired'
            }
          ]
        }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $match: {
          'datas.end_ts': {
            '$lte': date
          }
    }
  },
  {
      $group:{
          "_id":"$_id",
          "a":{$push:"$$ROOT"}
      }
  },
  {
      $project:{
          "_id":1,
          "a.data":1
      }
  }
])
])
```

Is there any other way which deletes and returns the docs. So that I just can save the returned doc to other collection.

Can I use `$out` here to do that? I am not sure. Any help which reduces the network round trip time is desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can use `$out` to push a new collections. Since you need to add some data from one collection to another collection, `$out` helps efficiently and reduce programmatical time and codes.

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("data.risk_status").in("inactive","expired")),
        unwind("$data"),
        // all other stages
        o->new Document("$out","NEW_COLLECTION_NAME")

).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());
```

Note : `$out` must be the last stage of aggregation. Ref [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/).

Comment: Is it possible to delete also in the same?

Comment: The question you asked is, you need to remove something from documents of one collection and add it to another collection. You can do it query level, then using `$out` u save in another collection. If you need remove something using programmatically by java in middle, hope you need to do it with another update or delete query.